# Angular2+ PDF Viewer to get co-ordinates of specific point

Tags: angular, pdf.js

guys, I am working on a digital signature application. Application is based on angular 5. I am viewing pdf by using `ng2-pdf-viewer`, now what I need to do is that a user needs to place a rectangle anywhere on the page loaded by `ng2-pdf-viewer`. So, when a user places the rectangle I need to get the exact coordinates of that location where the rectangle is placed so next time when I get the pdf opened again the user will see the rectangle on the same location.

Is there any solution how can I achieve this? I will be really thankful if someone guides me a proper solution to achieve this.

Thankyou